# How can I output a multiply expression in a Django template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, view

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  On my view, how can I output an expression?  I would like to do

```
<td>{{ fp_stat.avg_score * dow_index }}</td>
```

but I get this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' * dow_index' from 'fp_stat.avg_score * dow_index'
```

I would prefer not to create an additional attribute in my model, but if that's the only way then I guess I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing using template filters.

For example;

```
@register.filter
def multiply(value, arg):
    try:
        return value * arg
    except Exception:
        return ''
```

So you could do `{{ fp_stat.avg_score|multiply:dow_index }}`

And there is a package for this which does a much better job of implementing this type of filter;

https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/